# How to remove and disable access to General Settings Page including its link

Tags: multisite, admin-menu, sub-menu

How to remove and disable access to General Settings Page including its link on the Settings Tab and add a new link as General Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin called "[Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/)" that can do just this. I have used it numerous times without issues.